# Opamp isolation buffer behind phototransistor

Tags: operational-amplifier, phototransistor

Part of a PCB I designed looks like this:

[image: Phototransistor]

Simple phototransistor with a resistor to measure the voltage over. More light => more voltage over the resistor.

However, the circuit behind the output doesn't like it when the impedance of its input is too high. Lacking a better idea, I decided to try what effect an opamp as isolation buffer would have:

[image: Amplified]

The opamp (LM358N) got hot and didn't perform as expected.

VDD is 3.3V, not even close to the maximum V<sub>in</sub> the LM358 is rated for.

Did I cut a corner I shouldn't have cut or did I make a seriously stupid mistake here?

To avoid any confusion: the circuit without opamp works exactly as intended. Just not in combination with the next stage of the design.

Comment: How did you connect the other op-amp in the LM358 package? If you left it's inputs unconnected, it's possible that it's oscillating and that's what's heating up.

Comment: @ThePhoton All unused inputs are directly connected to GND.

Comment: That's still a potential problem. Configure the other op amp as a follower with the input grounded.

Comment: When T6 conducts it will pull the +ve input to the op-amp up towards Vdd. But an LM358 is not a rail-rail op-amp, and it doesn't work well when the +ve input gets within 1.5V of Vdd. You need to use a rail-rail op-amp.

Comment: @SteveG I could've sworn I picked a rail-to-rail, wow, that's a major mistake there.

Comment: The 358 is a clever design which is often extremely useful in single-supply circuits, since it will operate with inputs at the negative rail (ground). But that's not actually rail-to-rail.

Comment: Replacing the op-amp by a MAX4036 or similar would solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When T6 conducts it will pull the +ve input to the op-amp up towards Vdd. But an LM358 is not a rail-rail op-amp, and it doesn't work well when the +ve input gets within 1.5V of Vdd. You need to use a rail-rail op-amp. –
> [Steve G](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/96794/steve-g)
> Mar 26, 2016 at 22:24

Replacing the op-amp with a proper rail-to-rail capable one did indeed fix the problem. I had picked the wrong type of op-amp.